# Use substitution to find the antiderivatives in terms of the unspecified function 

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

[Recall that $f^{(p)}$ denotes the $p$th derivative of $f$, and $f^{p}$ is the $p$th power of f.]

a.  $\int [5^3() + 7^2() − 3]\cdot f'() x$

b. $\int csc^2(3f'(x))\cdot f''(x)dx$

c. $∫\frac{f^{(p)}(x)}{f^{(p−1)}(x)}dx$

I don't know why this unspecified concept is throwing me off. Can someone help? I'm in Calculus 1

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22025/is-it-required-to-use-mathjax-for-simple-listings-of-numbers) for mathematical objects, such as variables.  Here's the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Chain rule galore.